# request proxy and relative links

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

In my expressJS setup, I am having it use the Request module to load an external url and pipe it to the response.

Example:

```
app.all('/otherApp', function (req, res) {

    request.get({
        url:'http://myotherapp.mysite.com'
    }).pipe(res);

});
```

This will load the external site as expected, but none of the actual content. I believe what happens is that all of the calls made from that page will now be processed by my own app, rather than theirs. So for instance if it tries to load an image, it will look for that image on my own application and of course not find it.

I am not able to find any documentation on the request package that would explain how to overcome this limitation.

Comment: problem isn't request itself, but the recovered content. you'll need not only to pipe it to the destination, you'll need to rewrite every url inside the content in order to make the proxied site recover the remaining content from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Sombriks I'm guessing there isn't any middleware out there that helps do this since it is probably very use case specific